# Is there way to disable google maps resize when DOM is changed?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework

I'm working on ionic app and currently struggling with app performance on Android. Ionic modal opening animation is slow on Android. Using chrome timeline I figured out that when modal is opening google maps are resized and re-rendered which causes lags in modal animation. I tried to hide map container before modal show and display it after hide. Animation became a bit better but not enough. Is there any way to disable angular google maps resize?

Answer (score 0):

can put ng-if on map div and handle when DOM changes
check directive [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25611012/scope-variable-not-updating-in-dom-after-event-listener-changes-it)